# Database Subscriptions - Do Not Disturb mode

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cksubscription

## Problem:

I am not receiving subscription changes (notifications) to `private` and `shared databases`, when the device is in **Do Not Disturb Mode** (even when the app is in **foreground**).

#### Note:

When device is not in **Do Not Disturb mode**, I receive subscription changes as and when they occur.

## Code:

**Registering remote notifications:**

```
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

**Database subscriptions:**

```
let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: "Test")
let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
```

**Receiving Notification:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo)
    
    dataService.receivedCloudKitNotification(notification,
                                             completionBlock: completionHandler)
}
```

Since I am not using sound / badge / alert / carplay (`UNAuthorizationOptions`), I had opted for the above method.

## My Assumption:

- I was assuming that **Do Not Disturb** would be applicable only for anything that would alert the user visually / or through sound.
- I was assuming silent notifications are for data changes and wouldn’t be affected by it. (Just like they don’t require any authorisation)

## Questions:

1. Am I missing any steps for the above mentioned problem ?
2. On a different scenario, When app is **not** in **Do Not Disturb** mode but **Background Refresh** is turned off for the app I don’t receive subscription changes notifications though the app is in foreground.